# jQuery scripts not working in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, object, scripting

I'm converting a PHP project into CakePHP and having issues with pre-defined jQuery scripts like datepicker, text editors etc.

Here are my CSS, script being added on the page: (if you right click on page and click page source)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cakeskite/css/common.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cakeskite/css/creatorcommon.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cakeskite/css/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cakeskite/css/cssbuttons.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cakeskite/css/jquery-te-1.4.0.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cakeskite/css/jquery.datepick.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/cakeskite/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cakeskite/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cakeskite/js/jquery.simplemodal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cakeskite/js/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cakeskite/js/jquery.ptTimeSelect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cakeskite/js/jquery-te-1.4.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cakeskite/js/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cakeskite/js/creatorcommon.js"></script>
```

If I click on any link, it shows that file is present, so it's not the issue of file not found. I can check that in chrome console too

I added my scripts in layout file like this:

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->css('common');
echo $this->Html->css('creatorcommon');
echo $this->Html->css('jquery-ui');
echo $this->Html->css('cssbuttons');
echo $this->Html->css('jquery-te-1.4.0');
echo $this->Html->css('jquery.datepick');

echo $this->Html->script('jquery');
echo $this->Html->script('jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min');
echo $this->Html->script('jquery.simplemodal');
echo $this->Html->script('jquery.datepick');
echo $this->Html->script('jquery.ptTimeSelect');
echo $this->Html->script('jquery-te-1.4.0');
echo $this->Html->script('common');
echo $this->Html->script('creatorcommon');

echo $scripts_for_layout;
?>
```

I put all my CSS and script files in webroot/js & webroot/css folders

I'm getting the errors like:

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'datepick'
```

whereas they are working in non-cakephp projects. Here are the lines from html and script files

Note: I'm using ajax to load up things and I'm binding the controls when I receive the data

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'loadtests',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'category_id=' + category_id + '&subcategory_id=' + subcategory_id,
    success: function(result){

        stopLoading();
        if(!isSessionExpired(result)){

            $(".msg").html("&nbsp;");

            if(result.indexOf("No tests found...")>-1){
                $(".tests").html("No tests found...");
            }
            else{
                $(".tests").html(result);

                $(".testfound").css("display","block");
                $(".durationrow").css("display","block");
                $(".noduration").css("display","none");             

                disableKeyPress($("input[name='startdate']"));
                disableKeyPress($("input[name='enddate']"));
                disableKeyPress($("input[name='starttime']"));
                disableKeyPress($("input[name='endtime']"));

                $("input[name='startdate']").datepick({dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd', changeMonth: false});
                $("input[name='enddate']").datepick({dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd', changeMonth: false});
                $("input[name='starttime']").ptTimeSelect();
                $("input[name='endtime']").ptTimeSelect();

                $(".datepicker").css("display","block");
                $("select[name='test']").change(
                        function(){
                            checkTestDuration();
                        }
                    );

                checkTestDuration();
            }
        }
        else
            notLoggedIn();
    }
```

And here is my html form:

```
    <div class="createrow timebound testfound">
        <div class="column150 leftfloat">Start Date</div>
        <div class="column250 leftfloat">
            <input name="startdate" class="txt100" />
        </div>
        <div class="column150 leftfloat msg">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="createrow timebound testfound">
        <div class="column150 leftfloat">End Date</div>
        <div class="column250 leftfloat">
            <input name="enddate" class="txt100" />
        </div>
        <div class="column150 leftfloat msg">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="createrow timebound testfound">
        <div class="column150 leftfloat">Start Time</div>
        <div class="column250 leftfloat">
            <input name="starttime" class="txt100" />
        </div>
        <div class="column150 leftfloat msg">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="createrow timebound testfound">
        <div class="column150 leftfloat">End Time</div>
        <div class="column250 leftfloat">
            <input name="endtime" class="txt100" />
        </div>
        <div class="column150 leftfloat msg">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check what method is defined in `jquery.datepick`.

Comment: @Arun, the same code is working in non-cakephp based project

Also, none of the external scripts working like datepicker, timepicker, text editor etc.

Comment: what triggers the jquery script?

Comment: How are your scripts being output in the HTML? Do you see outputs like `<script type="text/javascript" src="/cakeskite/js/jquery.js"></script>`, without `/cakesite/` or nothing at all?

Comment: @user221931 Yes, it outputs with /cakeskite/js/jquery.js
You can see at the top of the page, Thanks

Comment: @ayo akinyemi

whenever someone click the textbox, a date picker should popup.
Now that is working in non-cakephp project, here is the line:

    $("input[name='startdate']").datepick({dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',  changeMonth: false});

The text box is defined like this:

    <input type="text" name="startdate"/>

The problem is none of the external scripts are working
The scripts written by me are working
Also, the script files are linking properly
The jquery version i'm using is  1.10.2

Comment: Is the method really called `datepick`? The jquery UI plugin call is `datepicker`.

Comment: Please have a look at following screenshots

1.   http://tinypic.com/r/343iwqv/5

Comment: 2.  http://tinypic.com/r/2vbmx5d/5

Comment: 3.  http://tinypic.com/r/2iurtpk/5

Answer (score 0):

I tried hard to find the solution and I came near to 90%

I created another project using cakephp and used only time selector and that worked fine

Hence, I conclude there is some conflict in the script files included

I'll try and post if i find